# Is it a right place for finding the reason of why my post removed?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, rules

is it a right place to get a comments on why the answer was removed? I posted a direct link to the product, which is exactly an answer to the question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330472/look-for-modern-monitoring-and-graphing-solution-other-than-cacti, but it was deleted, without any comments on why it was deleted.

I understand you are trying to protect from spam, but there was a request for the monitoring solution using specified library and I provided a direct reference to the just launched product.

Could you, please, provide a bit more light on what I did wrong, as I definitely wants to play  fair.

I checked the same kind of questions before posting mine, but didn't find anything matching my case.

Comment: *"I posted a direct link to the product"* ... if it was only a link it might have been removed for being a "link-only answer". Or, perhaps more likely, it might have been flagged/deleted as spam.

Comment: It looks like self promoting/advertisement which is frowned upon. If you can edit it to appear less like advertisement someone here can flag it for you and ask to undelete. However the question itself is off topic on Stack Overflow so not sure it's still relevant.

Comment: Please review the [FAQ#promotion] for details on how you can promote your product on the [SE] network.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, thanks. From what I can see I followed all of the rules mentioned there: the question is there and I mentioned my affiliations to the product.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - thanks, updated to reflect the fact that it's a demonstration / proof of what could be done using the library. Does it looks like it could be flagged to be restored?

Comment: @Alexander done. Will keep you updated how it goes, note it's not sure at all my flag will be accepted but it's worth trying.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, thank you. At the end, the whole question was removed, but still - thanks for your help and trying ;)

Comment: Oh my, hope it wasn't my flag that triggered the final deletion!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I'm a newbie here and pleased to get a prompt answer and a support anyway =)

Comment: Cheers Alexander that's what we're here for... though Meta isn't always a welcoming place.